# Capability of storing something

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-requests, adjectives

So, if `storable` *stands for capable of being stored*, what *adjective* will stand for *capable for storing something*?
Case of word-usage - is programming, interfaces* naming in particular
Thanks in advance.

**Interface - in other words is capability of object to do particular actions, e.g.: `MovableInterface` - which means, that object can be moved, etc*

Comment: Storage? But I use a cupboard myself.

Comment: @Mari-LouA it has to be an adjective. Sorry, my question wasn't clear enough and it's fixed now. Thanks for reply anyway!

Comment: How would this word be used? Can you supply an example sentence?

Comment: @Mari-LouA it's kind of a special case of a word-usage: for example: `storableInterface` which means capability of entity to be stored. I need the same naming format for entities, which have capability of storing something.

Comment: So it's not about "English" per se, it's for naming something on a computer programme. Sorry, I'm not a developer or a programmer, can't help you there. EDIT: You need to edit your question and explain your problem properly.

Comment: Unfortunately 'shelvable' isn't a real word.

Comment: Something that can store something is a _container_ - a very common word used in programming as well.

Comment: @oerkelens it is, but adjective is the only appropriate option for this case. Otherwise, i'd go just with `StorageInterface` or something like that

Answer (score 1):

A single word that might meet your requirement is:

> capacious

[Capacious](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/capacious) can be used in a lot of situations to mean  capable of storing something,  as your question asks. And, would be a reasonable choice if there were no specific type of storage involved.
Other words might work for what you want, but *capacious* seems the most likely candidate for [having a lot of space and able to contain a lot](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/capacious),

Comment: Seems like. Thanks for reply! If no other answers will be provided within a day, I'll chek yours as correct, as closest answer so far.

Comment: I came back to this root a number of times through the idea of 'capacity' (I was also toying with empty )  The thing is, capacious almost always means "big" or suggesting more than expected space .. not a handy small space.

Comment: Yeah, *capacity* is, well, the ability to hold - and also of course a synonym for *capability*, *ambit* and *remit* :)

Comment: @WillCrawford yep .. which makes it vague without taking Mari-Lou-A initial comment that using storage as a modifier to something. That is really the far most common way... and if you look at existing storage references that's what they do (storage capacity, good storage area).  Storable storage containers works fine. If an item need checkbox boolean traits,  he could use storage_capacity storageCapacity or storagecapacity ... usually displaynames need massaging anyway.

Answer (score 1):

How about "Fillable" ...able to be filled ?

> [**fillable** at Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/fillable)
>
> able to be filled

While not precisely about storage, it nearly always is ultimately about ability to receive and hold until needed.

Exceptions would be to 'fill a need' or 'fill an order' .. however many of those really should use "fulfilable'

Seriously though.. If you mean storage capacity, say it (storage_capacity, storageCapacity , storagecapacity )... better than confusing things.

Comment: As a variable name in programming, I think this is more consistent with "storable" than "capacious", which in general English also has the unintended implication of having a **large** capacity. Much better.

Comment: This one might be interesting aswell. Though, the main thing about this word is - filling an object,(so I can fill it, then whatsoever will happens later I don't care) whileI need it to be representing ability to hold items inside in amount of time.